# C++ link issue after switching to /MT

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I am working on application which should be running on any Windows NT machine. Today I was trying to deploy my application on new machine and suddenly get error that `msvcp100.dll` is missing. I've started digging into that problem and found solution. Only what I had to do is in project configurations change `Run time library` From `/MD`to `Multi-threaded (/MT)`.

But after switching to current mode I am getting link error. Not sure why and how to fix it. Could you please help me to figure that out? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't supposed to deploy debug builds.  Compile with Release settings (including release version of the run-time library) and you won't have that problem.  (You can enable debug information on a release build... it's use of the debug libraries that causes problems)

Answer (score 2):

The error comes from that when compiling in debug mode, you'll need to change your project to link with link with debug libraries, ie **`msvcmrtd.lib`** instead of `msvcmrt.lib` and **`msvcrtd.lib`** instead of `msvcrt.lib`

Deploying debug binaries to other machines may/will cause runtime problems though since the debug version sof the DLLs aren't (afaik) redistributable, what you probably want to do is to fix your release build.